# AWS ECS service is failing to launch a task with a container which is Node js Express app running on port 3000

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to deploy a simple Node Express application on AWS Elastic Container Service. My app is very simple, which has only one js file called app.js with below code.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));

app.get('/health', (req, res) => res.send('OK'));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Before I do anything I created two security groups, one for my ECS task and the other one for the application load balancer as I will be using load balancer for my ECS tasks.

This is the inbound rules configuration of my security group for ECS task called, `ecs-task-sg`:

[image]

This is the inbound rules configuration of my security group for my load balancer called, `ecs-alb-sg`:

[image]

Then I built my app docker image and pushed it to ECR repository. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --omit=dev

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

I built the image locally running the following commands:

- `docker build -f Dockerfile -t noderestapi .`
  Then I run the app locally to check if everything is working as expected
- `docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name noderestapi noderestapi`
  Everything was fine and and I could see the app is running on localhost:3000.

Then I created an ECR repository to store my image. I also authenticated to the ECR from my machine. Repository is private and Tag immutability is enabled.

Then I tagged the image by running the following command:

- `docker tag noderestapi:latest 1234556677.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/noderestapi:v1`

Then I pushed the image to the ECR repository:

- `docker push 1234556677.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/noderestapi:v1`

Everything worked as expected. I can see the image in the ECR repository.

Then I started configuring the Elastic Container Service to launch my application.

First I created ECS task definition following the steps mentioned below:

[image]

Environment:

[image]

I created the task definition using the settings mentioned in the screenshots above.

After that, I created an ECS cluster for Fargate (within the default VPC). I just entered the name for the cluster basically, `noderestapi-cluster`.

Then I created service for the cluster following the steps mentioned below.

I clicked on the Create button:

[image]

Then I chose Fargate as Launch Type:

[image]

Then under the Deployment configuration section, I chose the task definition I created:

[image]

Under the NETWORKING section, I chose the security group I created for my task, `ecs-task-sg`.

Then under the Load Balancer, I chose to create a new Application Load Balancer:

[image]

[image]

Then I created the service. After a few minutes, the service was fully created.

After the service was created, I went to load balancer to correct the security group of my load balancer. It was assigned the security group for the ECS task. So I assigned the correct one I created for the load balancer earlier, `ecs-alb-sg`. Then I opened the DNS of the load balancer and I got the 503 error. Then I checked my ECS cluster and I could see that service is struggling to launch the task.

[image]

[image]

What is wrong with my configuration and how can I fix it?

Also in the CloudWatch, I am getting this error.

```
exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error
```

Answer (score 0):

The container you have selected in the load balancer's setting is `noderestapi 80:80`. That doesn't look correct. It should say port `3000` on that, not port `80`.

Also, the screenshots you show for creating the container have the name `nodeapi` not `noderestapi`.

It looks like you created another container or task definition configured to use port `80` instead of `3000`. However without also changing the settings in your docker image, that will never work.

I suggest editing the task definition port to `3000`, and editing the target group to change the traffic port and health check port to `3000`, to match the port that your container is actually listening on. Only the load balancer listener should be using port `80` everything else (task definition, target group, etc) should reflect the actual port the container is listening on.

Comment: I have updated the screenshot to show you the one I used. Actually I used the right image for the load balancer. I just uploaded the wrong screenshot.

Comment: I tried again and it's still not working.

Comment: I don't see the option where I have to specify the port for health check.

Comment: Does the log for the ECS task say that the container started? I would add logging so you can see if the health check requests are getting to the app.

Comment: It's always pending and then the deployment failed.

Comment: I am also getting this error in the CloudWatch. `exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error`

Comment: Hi, I found the issue finally. It is the operation system I chose.

Comment: The logs in CloudWatch were what I was referring to when I said "logs". The error message "exec format error" means you have an X86 docker image and you are deploying to a Graviton Fargate instance, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Check the security group inbound rule to add 3000 port